# Calling setInterval from requestAnimationFrame causes enemies to shoot continuously

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

I am making a 2D canvas game in JavaScript. I am trying to make the enemies shoot a bullet every 3 seconds.

```
for (var i = 0; i < enemyBullets.length; i++) {
    enemyBullets[i].show();
    enemyBullets[i].move();
}
// With this loop, whenever there is a bullet added to
// the array , it gets drawn on the canvas and updated.

function Enemy(x, y) {
   this.shoot = function(){
        var ebullet = new enemyBullet(this.x, this.y);
        enemyBullets.push(ebullet);
        // Here I have the enemy object and the function
        // which adds the bullet to the array.
    }
}
```

Here is how I use the `enemy.shoot` function in the `draw()` function, which is called via `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```
function lol(){
    for(var v = 0; v<enemies.length;v++){
        enemies[v].shoot();
    }
}
setTimeout(lol,3000); // This is what I've tried so far
```

When I do this, the enemies are not shooting a single bullet every 3 seconds as desired. Instead, 3 seconds after the beginning of the program, they start adding infinite bullets to the array and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Are you starting a new timeout every time you draw a frame? This looks similar to [the error explained in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/176158/39518) - not javascript, but the same overall idea of "start your timer once, don't stack an ever-increasing collection of timers".

Comment: I actually struggle a little bit reading this code , since i'm a beginner and i only know javascript. If you have the time to explain it , can you please do that

Comment: The code is not the part to look at. That's for Unity and doesn't relate to your issue. The reason I linked to this was for the explanation of what happens when you trigger a new times interval every time you draw a frame. You're not saying "keep ticking the timer I told you to start last frame" — that happens anyway. Instead you're starting a *new* timer that will finish a frame after the previous one. Stack up enough of these, and your enemies shoot every frame instead of only once every 3 seconds, because you have a whole stack of timeouts completing one after the other.

Comment: I tried it without the for loop and it actually worked , it shot once for every 3 seconds , but... it only shot from the first enemy and there are  two more left ... that's why i need to  loop throught the array of enemies , so i can use the shoot function , for each of the elements every 3 seconds , but it seems that setInterval and loops don't work with each other or im doing something wrong ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making an enemy shoot every few seconds](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176720/making-an-enemy-shoot-every-few-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` instead This will make the function get called multiple times.

The other option is to put a `setTimeout` call inside the `lol` function so it will be rescheduled.

To stop the scheduled call you can pass the return value of the `setInterval` or latest `setTimeout` to `clearInterval` or `clearTimeout` resp.

Comment: I tried with setInterval , it does the same thing , they start shooting 3 seconds after the program starts and when they start , they do it very fast and there is no delay.